# Определение текста с изображения. OCR

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Имеется онлайн игра. Мне нужно с нее получать текст. Примеры я показал стрелками на изображении. Пробовал Tesseract но он очень нестабильно определяет текст. Например в 3137 он мне пишет 3l3t. На скриншотах видно что я получаю в итоге. Как заставить его определять текст корректно? Пробовал обучить Tesseract с помощью jTessBoxEditor, лучше не стало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и собственно сам код

```
public static string GetText(Bitmap imgsource)
    {
        var ocrtext = string.Empty;
        // сос1 coc2 coc3 это мои попытки обучить tesseract новому шрифту который вытянул из игры.
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng+coc1+coc2+coc3", EngineMode.Default))
        {
           // engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(imgsource))
            {
                using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                {
                    ocrtext = page.GetText();
                }
            }
        }

        return ocrtext;
    }
```

Comment: Я так понимаю вам нужно распознавать , только цифры, в таком случае укажите `engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");`

Comment: Толку? Задача распознавания не только цифр. И вопрос был в другом, как достичь 100% точности распознавания. Сейчас уже стало лучше после того как программно накладываю фильтры на битмап, но все равно ошибки есть. 6 распознает как 5, 1 иногда не видит или распознает как i

Comment: Инвертируй картинку. Tesseract ожидает темные символы на светлом фоне, а не наоборот, как у вас.